# testing a link with codeception

Tags: php, symfony, codeception

I'm using codeception for the first time, and I'm trying to test a symfony route that has parameters. When I run the test, it doesn't get to the page and the test fails. I've never used codeception, so how I can I test a route that has parameter.

```
#[Route(/saisie/positer_particuliere/{plateform}/{dayNb}-{weekNb}-{year}', name: 'app_saisie_positer particulieres')]
```

```
public function jeVaisSurLeLienSaisiePositerParticulierel()
{
try {
$date_now = new DateTimeImmutable();
$dayNb = $date_now->format("N");
$weekNb = $date_now->format("W");
$year = $date_now->format("Y");

$this->I->amOnPage("/saisie/positer_particuliere/1/{$dayNb}-{$weekNb}-{$year}");
$this->I->click('1c-plateforme', '#1c-plateforme');
$this->I->see('select', 'plateforme');
} catch (Error Serror) {
throw new Error("Step je vais sur le lien saisie positer particuliere 1 is not defined", 1, _CLASS_
_LINE_);
```

Comment: Route is `{dayNb}-{weekNb}-{year}`, but you format it without `-`: `.$dayNb.$weekNb.$year`

Comment: i added - and it still doesn't work

Comment: Where does the code fail? What's the error? Do you actually have a page in your test environment with those parameters?